# undefined method `visit' for #<Object (NoMethodError) capybara rspec

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am getting an error undefined method `visit' for

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rubygems"
require "cucumber"
require "capybara"
require 'capybara/rspec/matchers'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

Comment: My test.rb file is 
    Given(/^I navigate to "([^"]*)"$/)do |url|
    Capybara.app_host = url
    visit('/')   
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber) you need to require 'capybara/cucumber' to include the capybara dsl methods into cucumber tests.  If you have an issue with doing that you'd need to call all the methods on current_session like `Capybara.current_session.visit('/')`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Capybara docs [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) there's a section *using the DSL elsewhere*

You can use this code:

```
require 'capybara/dsl'

# putting this at the top level will make capybara methods available everywhere
# you can put it in a module if you want to, well, modularize ...
include Capybara::DSL
```